# C#: Given src => src.property, code choosing property if you have a string "propertyname"?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, expression

I am using AutoMapper where it has:

```
.ForMember( dest => dest.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.id))
```

Using the far right expression `src => src.id`, if I have a string variable with the property's name, how would I choose the property by it?

I tried this:

```
src => propertyName
```

Then had to laugh when the value was "id".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection to get a property by name:

```
private R GetProperty<T, R>(T obj, string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    return (R)pi.GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Which you would use in AutoMapper like this:

```
.ForMember( dest => dest.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetProperty(src, propertyName)))
```

Comment: +1 But this code can be improved because currently it's not working for static properties/fields.

Comment: I interpret the AutoMapper use case as suggesting it only needs to get instance members from src, but you're certainly right that the same technique would work for static members.

Comment: Everything worked, with the exception of having the source be a "var" .Select() projection, which has a type of "object", and AutoMapper didn't find any fields to map.  LOL.

Comment: Updated with a generic parameter, though GetType() should return the most specific type. Unless I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: Your part worked fine. Way back to how I am using your code, I am trying to Automap between a POCO and a set of arbitrary properties selected by .Select( p => new {p.custid, p.custname}) (for example).  AutoMapper doesn't find any properties that are the same names, even though they exist.

Comment: For example, I have a Customer POCO where I try to map between a var a = Customer.Select( p => new {p.ID, p.name, p.phone}); and a var b = new Customer();

Comment: Glad to help. You'll probably want to create a new question (or update an existing one) to discuss your other issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the name of the property you wish to access, you would use reflection to get MemberInfo and then invoke the property from the MemberInfo.

```
src => src.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetGetMethod().Invoke(src, new object[] {})
```

Of course, this tidbit assumes **src** has properties and that propertyName identifies a property on the object.

Comment: Sweet, looking forward to the answer.